# i am getting an error of cannot read property'get context' of null

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="GameArea"></canvas>
<script>

var myGamePiece;

 myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);




function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    console.log("component  called");
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y; 
   var  myGameArea=document.getElementById("startGame"); 
   console.log("myGameArea");  
    var ctx = myGameArea.getContext("2d");
    console.log("crossed");
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

</script>

<p>We have added a component to our game, a red square!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

//not able to getout of my error
in the above code i tried to create a rectangle on calling some function named component.
it created a rectangle by context but i am getting a error

Comment: Please learn to debug your code yourself. Read the error message and try to understand it. `startGame` is not the same as `GameArea`.

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas has an id of "GameArea", but you're trying to do getElementById("startGame").

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas element id is "GameArea" but you refer in code as "startGame". That is why it is null